# php space error when - but when i hit f12 and look at page there are no spaces, but if i look at the console it has spaces when it sends the URL

Tags: php, html

I have an image that I fetch with a php file...

here is how it shows when I hit f12 and look at the page...

```
<img src="/php_scripts/getimage.php?id='389955c8-4fc6-4596-a308-0345283c4812'&type=2" alt="card image" height="100" width="200" />
```

however it is failing and shows up on the console page as

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://webpage.com/php_scripts/getimage.php?id=%27389955c8-4fc6-4596-a308-0345283c4812%27&type=2".
```

notice now there is spacing at the beginning and end??

Why is this happening?

here is the actual source php

```
<div id="companylogo">
                    <img src="php_scripts/getimage.php?id='<?php echo $cardUUID?>'&type=2" alt="card image" height="100" width="200" />
                    </div>
```

if I do var_dump($cardUUID)
it does not have a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it has to do with the spacing and not the single quotes?

Try this:

```
<div id="companylogo">
    <img src="php_scripts/getimage.php?id=<?php echo $cardUUID?>&type=2" alt="card image" height="100" width="200" />
</div>
```

Comment: that's workings... why? shouldn't it show up on the elements page

Comment: @morty346 Depending... the PHP page was returning content so it wouldn't necessarily return a 404 cannot be found. Don't forget to accept my answer if it's working!

Comment: no I get that my getimage was returning an error, what I am asking is why does the ' not show up as spacing on the elements page?

Comment: @morty346 Oh, it's showing the encoded ' which is %27. Much like a space ' ' character will be displayed as %20. Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding